# CSS styling, how to make this button stay on the right side and be responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The comments button appears once someone adds a comment (ala medium.com). The p tag which holds the text is inside a bootstrap container which goes down the middle of the page. I want to keep my comments button to the right of that p paragraph.

Here's the screenshot of what I have currently. 
[image: After comment entered]

As I make the page smaller, the button slides to the left eventually going all the way to the left side of the screen. When it comes to absolute and relative positioning I get a bit confused as I haven't worked with it much. I'm hoping you guys can guide me here.

My ultimate goal here is to keep the comments button to the right of the p tag (the paragraph) even while user is making the page smaller horizontally. If the button has to get responsively smaller, that's ok.

Here's the html and css:

```css
html, body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    height: 100%;
}

.headLine {
    text-align: center;
}

.highLight {
    background-color: yellow
}

.editable {
    position: relative;
}

.toolTip {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    min-width: 180px;
    max-width: 180px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white
}

.buttons {
    margin-top: 0.3%;
    color: black;
    background-color: #7D98ED;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.commentBox {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: beige;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}

.textAreaBox {
    width: 270px;
    height: 100px;
}

.buttonCommentSubmit {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 135px;        
}

.sideComment {
    position: absolute;
    right: 300px;
    top: 125px;
}

.sideCommentView {
    position: absolute;
    left: 69.5%;
    top: 15.7%;
    background-color: beige;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.mainTextBody {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: mintcream;
}

.reinsertedText {
    display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div className = "container mainTextBody" onMouseDown={this.removetoolBox.bind(this)} onMouseUpCapture={this.captureSelection.bind(this)}>
    <h1 className = "headLine" >Medium Markup</h1>
        <hr />
           <p className='editable'>All the text here....</p>
          {(this.state.showSideComments) ? <SideComments /> : ''}
</div>
      
<div className="sideComment">
   <button id="sideButton" onClick={this.showComments}>Comments</button>
</div>
```

EDIT: for more information and the html, here's a link to the github components:

https://github.com/milosbunijevac/medRails/tree/master/app/javascript/packs

and to the stylesheet:

https://github.com/milosbunijevac/medRails/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/main_control.scss

The only components I really used in this example are Main.jsx and SideComments.jsx

Comment: Tried `float: left` yet? I suggest dropping absolute positioning when it comes to responsive design.

You can, however, put the elements in a wrapper div, which would then allow the button to have `right: 0` at the rightmost part of its parent.

Comment: Can you please include the HTML your Angular application **outputs**. It's almost impossible to solve your problem without working HTML provided in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: right: 300px; might be your issue here on small screens.

Comment: http://learnlayout.com/position.html

Comment: @ObsidianAge I added the JSX components and the stylesheets in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 suggestions to keep the button to the right of the p tag. But I needed add a div to wrap your 2 divs.

#### display: inline-block + white-space: nowrap

```css
html, body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    height: 100%;
}

.headLine {
    text-align: center;
}

.highLight {
    background-color: yellow
}

.editable {
    position: relative;
}

.toolTip {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    min-width: 180px;
    max-width: 180px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white
}

.buttons {
    margin-top: 0.3%;
    color: black;
    background-color: #7D98ED;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.commentBox {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: beige;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}

.textAreaBox {
    width: 270px;
    height: 100px;
}

.buttonCommentSubmit {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 135px;        
}

.sideComment {
    position: absolute;
    right: 300px;
    top: 125px;
}

.sideCommentView {
    position: absolute;
    left: 69.5%;
    top: 15.7%;
    background-color: beige;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.mainTextBody {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: mintcream;
}

.reinsertedText {
    display:inline;
}

.wrapContainer {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.wrapContainer>div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapContainer">
    <div className = "container mainTextBody" onMouseDown={this.removetoolBox.bind(this)} onMouseUpCapture={this.captureSelection.bind(this)}>
        <h1 className = "headLine" >Medium Markup</h1>
            <hr />
               <p className='editable'>All the text here....</p>
          {(this.state.showSideComments) ? <SideComments /> : ''}
    </div>
      
    <div className="sideComment">
       <button id="sideButton" onClick={this.showComments}>Comments</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### display: flex

```css
html, body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    height: 100%;
}

.headLine {
    text-align: center;
}

.highLight {
    background-color: yellow
}

.editable {
    position: relative;
}

.toolTip {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    min-width: 180px;
    max-width: 180px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white
}

.buttons {
    margin-top: 0.3%;
    color: black;
    background-color: #7D98ED;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.commentBox {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: beige;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}

.textAreaBox {
    width: 270px;
    height: 100px;
}

.buttonCommentSubmit {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 135px;        
}

.sideComment {
    position: absolute;
    right: 300px;
    top: 125px;
}

.sideCommentView {
    position: absolute;
    left: 69.5%;
    top: 15.7%;
    background-color: beige;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.mainTextBody {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: mintcream;
}

.reinsertedText {
    display:inline;
}

.wrapContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.wrapContainer>div {
    flex: 1;
}
.wrapContainer>div + div {
    flex: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapContainer">
    <div className = "container mainTextBody" onMouseDown={this.removetoolBox.bind(this)} onMouseUpCapture={this.captureSelection.bind(this)}>
        <h1 className = "headLine" >Medium Markup</h1>
            <hr />
               <p className='editable'>All the text here....</p>
          {(this.state.showSideComments) ? <SideComments /> : ''}
    </div>
      
    <div className="sideComment">
       <button id="sideButton" onClick={this.showComments}>Comments</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can change the margins and positions, but it maybe is beyond your main problem.